# Vue : Vue Formulate input custom error message

Tags: vue.js

I using [Vue Formulate](https://vueformulate.com/) for form validation. When submit the error message show `Formid is required.`, but I want `Form ID is required`

```
  <FormulateForm
    class="login-form"
    v-model="formValues"
    @submit="submitHandler"
  >
    <FormulateInput
      name="formid"
      type="text"
      label="Form ID"
      placeholder=""
      validation="required"

    />
    <FormulateInput
      type="submit"
      label="Log In"
    />
  </FormulateForm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom validation message [link](https://vueformulate.com/guide/validation/#custom-validation-rules) , `validation-name` props to replace default `name`

```
  <FormulateForm
    class="login-form"
    v-model="formValues"
    @submit="submitHandler"
  >
    <FormulateInput
      name="formid"
      type="text"
      label="Form ID"
      placeholder=""
      validation="required"
      validation-name="Form ID"
    />
    <FormulateInput
      type="submit"
      label="Log In"
    />
  </FormulateForm>
```